# How to get docdb emulator docker container to run?

Tags: docker, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I just installed cosmos db using this url [docker setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#running-on-docker)

I have this folder %LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulator\bind-mount
And I installed the certs
I am new to docker. Do I need to docker run using the command below?
How do I find https://??/_explorer/index.html ?
I get a error when I run the container :

```
C:\>
C:\>docker run --name azure-cosmosdb-emulator --memory 2GB --mount 
"type=bind,source=%LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulator\bind-   
mount,destination=C:\CosmosDB.Emulator\bind-mount" --interactive --tty -p 
8081:8081 -p 8900:8900 -p 8901:8901 -p 8902:8902 -p 10250:10250 -p 
10251:10251 -p 10252:10252 -p 10253:10253 -p 10254:10254 -p 10255:10255 
-p 10256:10256 -p 10350:10350 microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/azure-cosmosdb-emulator" is already in use by container 
"a7566570305eb1adf7c0f41a73e9e73c17ae061a6333123f2b121947ab3658ca". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this container sleeping in your docker system. You can run the following command to view all containers, including the sleeping ones.

```
docker container ls -a
```

In your case, you can just run

```
docker start azure-cosmosdb-emulator
```

to startup CosmosDB emulator again.

When CosmosDB Emulator is running as a docker image then you can access it using this URL:

```
https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html
```

I've written more about CosmosDB Emulator from Docker in this [blog post](https://www.johanohlin.com/blog/develop-with-cosmosdb-in-docker/).